# Paper JS detect closed path

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, paperjs

Paper JS reference has boolean math operations which checks one object against another object.

Problem is I see it's not enough to accomplish what I need which is to detect a closed path whether it be self-intersecting or two or more objects intersecting each other.

As a reference on below image, i cannot find a solution for the first two at the top. The image below which has the green fill works fine since the path is connected to the first mouse-down point.

[image: paper js fill closed path]

Comment: One good thing about paper.js is that they have a reasonably good referance, so in 15 seconds I found http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#getintersections-path  PathItem.getItersections that will solve the top left. The top right you can use the Path object http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#intersects-item . When you use 3rd party code it is always best to spend some time reading the entire reference, it will help you write better code and solve problems like this in less time than it takes to type the question.

Comment: Yep. Came across both. intersects(item) does not work when checking on same item. getIntersections() seem to work but cannot get an optimized solution. Just now I thought of something for the getIntersections() to detect the click area so I can only loop through the items in that area to check against.

Comment: Just break the shapes into their component parts (lines, curves) then you can check for self intersection.